# Socket IPEndPoint in Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, communication

I have error. Code:
[image]

I my code I cannot use IPEndPoint, but in Console App I can do it. How can I reapir it, and whats the preblem?

Comment: Sounds like a missing reference. What does show if you hover over the tiny blue bar which is shown below IPEndPoint in your screen shot?

btw: Stackoverflow has a nice, auto-formatting code function in the text editor. Use it.

Comment: It told me, that is missing reference, but how can I add her there? It works in console.

Comment: There are more options in the drop down list which appears. Visual Studio comes up with possible solutions to the missing reference. One might be to add using System.Net, which could be the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the namespace System.Net - you have included System.Net.Sockets but the class IPEndPoint is not in this namespace.